# A simple "how to" document for Firefox Android add-on development

Tags: android, mobile, firefox-addon

Its almost 24 hours to see atleast one simple addon working on my android emulator firefox. Seems like all in vain. I wanted to create an add-on using [cfx tool](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.12/dev-guide/tutorials/mobile.html). I'm able to install the plugin but I don't know how to debug the add-on (as it is not working), I tried to put some `console.log` in the code and tried to see it in `logcat`, but nothing there..

I've searched extensively to find atleast one simple example for the same, but unfortunately I didn't get anything.

Bytheway my add-on's motive is to modify the html content in the page.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: i found [this useful documentation](https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2012/02/06/mobile-add-on-development-using-the-add-on-sdk/) after searching for Add-on sdk 1.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

okay guys, I figured it out and completed a working add-on on my emulator.

here are few links which will help..

[Mozilla cfx add-on sdk 1.5 zip file](https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/labs/jetpack/addon-sdk-1.5.zip)

[Mozilla cfx add-on sdk documentation](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.12/dev-guide/tutorials/mobile.html)

[Mobile Add-on development](https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2012/02/06/mobile-add-on-development-using-the-add-on-sdk/)

[Working Example](https://github.com/ZER0/penny-arcade-comics)

I hope this information will help.

Comment: also I want to add that I tried with `sdk 1.11` and `1.12` but the `cfx run` command was not working with **android emulator**, but when i used `sdk 1.5` it worked fine. Whereas I built my add-on with `sdk 1.11` and tested it on different phones. It worked fine.. :)

Comment: Can you give me a sample code for the example. Can we write the code in java?